# What is the byte content of Raspberry Active Source hdmi-cec message?

Tags: boot, hardware, hdmi, debian

When a Raspberry Pi is connected to a CEC bus with HDMI it sends an active source cec message on boot. This can be modified in `/boot/config.txt` with setting `hdmi_ignore_cec_init` either 1 or 0 as described in the [RPI docs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html).

Now what is the byte content of the message send by the RPI, so one could replicate it with tools such as `cec-utils` e.g. `echo "tx <rpi-cec-message-sent-on-boot>" | cec-client -s -d 1` ?

The easiest way to find this out would probably to have a second Raspberry Pi monitoring the bus while the other one boots, but I only have 1 RPI, so I can not test it myself.

This is a summary of my full problem, I already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004517/raspberry-pi-turn-on-av-receiver-cec).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more digging, I finally found a solution to my specific problem.

For my setup, as described in my question, one can turn on the Harman Kardon AVR 156 by broadcasting an active source message with the physical address of the TV.

`echo "tx 1f:82:00:00" | cec-client -s -d 1`

A breakdown of the CEC Frame:

1 = Recording 1 (Raspberry Pi)

F = Broadcast

82 = Active Source

00 00 = ID (TV)

I hope this helps anyone stumbling on this in the future!